# WDS deployment installs fine, consistently fails to setup: how do I diagnose what went wrong?

Tags: wds, wim, mdt

I'm using WDS with a reference image and boot file from a Win 7 iso. I get it to successful install sans answer file however when it reboots and tries to set up services, devices, etc. it gives an error popup that claims I'll need to restart to resume.

How does one typically diagnose these errors when using WDS? This is my first time trying to use WDS in an enterprise environment and I'm not finding many troubleshooting options.

Should I just skip WDS and go straight to using MDT?

Comment: Does the install ever complete?

Comment: yes, install completes but the setup(black screen with star) after always fails midway. Even stranger, when I made the capture image....the computer I used required the setup again(but not the install). It also failed 3-4 times before It finally started setting up the devices and completed like normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the TechNet article ‘[Understanding Failures and Log Files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851579(v=WS.10).aspx)’ shows you where to get the logs you will need to troubleshoot this issue.

Second, I agree with Jim B, you should go straight to MDT. Integrating MDT and WDS is easy, as MDT creates LiteTouch Windows PE images that can be used in WDS as boot images to allow network booting into the MDT environment. When you setup MDT, use the SLSHARE= setting in the deployment share rules and MDT will collect all the log files in the deployment share for each machine that you deploy to. The MDT help files have the instructions for using the SLSHARE setting.

Last, if you are new to using MDT, the [Deploy Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dd641427.aspx) page of the Springboard Series on TechNet has many articles and videos to help you. The TechNet video ‘[Deployment Day Session 1: Introduction to MDT 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/tdbe12-deployment-day-session1.aspx) is a great video to get you started with using MDT.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

yes, skip the wds integration, use mdt to build a working deployment THEN you can go back and integrate with wds if you so choose.  wds gets the image to the target pc, so the error logs you are looking for would be on the target pc